# Merge values split in different columns overwriting the 0 values

Tags: python, pandas, merge, overwrite

I have a dataframe with some values split in different columns

[image]

Then i want to merge all of them so result should be something like

[image]

I check pandas tutorial but i could not find something similar

Probably not very difficult but i am running of time

Comment: It is not clear if C is the sum of the other columns or the maximum value. Will there only ever be one nonzero column in each row?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.max()` and apply it row-wise by specifying `axis=1`

```
import pandas as pd

# your data
# ===========================
c1 = [0,0,0,0,2,7]
c2 = [0,0,8,4,0,0]
c3 = [5,3,0,0,0,0]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(C1=c1,C2=c2,C3=c3))

print(df)


   C1  C2  C3
0   0   0   5
1   0   0   3
2   0   8   0
3   0   4   0
4   2   0   0
5   7   0   0

# processing
# ===========================

df.max(axis=1)

0    5
1    3
2    8
3    4
4    2
5    7
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas.DataFrame.sum) and sum row-wise:

```
In [134]:
df.sum(axis=1)

Out[134]:
0    5
1    3
2    8
3    4
4    2
5    7
dtype: int64
```

Using `sum` deals with any number of `0` values row-wise

Comment: Great but what about if i only want to sum or take the max from specific columns? To be more precise some of them have the same name (repeated) althought the values are split . Then i want merge the columns repeated